# Is there an equivalent of TransactionReceipt in EOS?

Tags: cleos

I have just started testing with accounts and I have now this working -

```
cleos get accounts EOS7UBaMK1Nm7ASLBFoHueYtp3YnnH4kEMdbeep7vxtASgHnctupE
```

> {   "account_names": [
>       "trevoro2"   ] }

I created this using a create method -

```
cleos create account eosio trevoro2 EOS7UBaMK1Nm7ASLBFoHueYtp3YnnH4kEMdbeep7vxtASgHnctupE EOS7UBaMK1Nm7ASLBFoHueYtp3YnnH4kEMdbeep7vxtASgHnctupE
```

> executed transaction:
>   c96905dee9a9652c8190f2d2bd5221bb0ac65a06b4381451107221c1076c91a8  200
>   bytes  406 us
>   eosio <= eosio::newaccount            {"creator":"eosio","name":"trevoro2","owner":{"threshold":1,"keys":[{"key":"EOS7UBaMK1Nm7ASLBFoHueYt...
>   warning: transaction executed locally, but may not be confirmed by the
>   network yet    ]

In Ethereum I used to check pendingTransactions and getTransactionReceipts. Is there anything similar in EOS? I want to check the txn hash which is generated to see exactly what it has created.

I guess I am seeking something like the geth web3 tools which enable a lot of functionality to check txns.

Answer (score 2):

**From eosjs module**

You can use [eosjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eosjs) node module to get tx status

```
 var txDetail = await eos.getTransaction(req.params.txid);
 console.log(txDetail.trx.receipt.status)
```

**From command line using cleos**

You can use `cleos` to get transaction details, and then use *trx.receipt.status* to check the status of your transaction

```
cleos get transaction txHash
```

**But do not forget to run nodeos with history plugin**

```
nodeos -e -p eosio --plugin eosio::chain_api_plugin --plugin eosio::history_api_plugin
```

Comment: Thanks. I will test now. I have to work out how to run nodeos from Docker. I have a docker installation.

Comment: Any idea what this could be - cleos get transaction c96905dee9a9652c8190f2d2bd5221bb0ac65a06b4381451107221c1076c91a8
Error 3200006: invalid http request
Error Details:
The server has rejected the request as invalid!
Please verify this url is valid: http://nodeosd:8888/v1/history/get_transaction
If the condition persists, please contact the RPC server administrator for nodeosd!

Comment: I guess you may not be running nodeos with history plugin. Is this issue coming for all txs or specific ones?

Comment: All txns. I got stuck on this. I raised a query in github as an issue. The docker compose file must be wrong.